# Position widgets in orbit around another widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

anyone has an idea on how's the best way to position widgets in orbit AROUND another (circular) widget in flutter like this? [image: Example]

Thank you very much for any help you can give :D

Comment: How about using stack

Comment: Best way is `CustomPainter`

Answer (score 2):

```dart
 /// from  https://gist.github.com/pskink/50554a116698f03a862a356c38b75eb3#file-rotary_dial-dart-L225
Iterable<Rect> getBounds(Rect rect, int length) sync* {
  final s = Size.square(rect.shortestSide / 6.5);
  final radius = (rect.shortestSide - s.shortestSide) * 0.40;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    /// distance +
    final angle = i * pi / 6 + pi * .01;
    final center = rect.center + Offset(cos(angle), sin(angle)) * radius;
    yield Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: s.width, height: s.height);
  }
}
class Avatar3xBtnMultiChildLayoutDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  final double iconSize;
  Avatar3xBtnMultiChildLayoutDelegate(this.iconSize);

  @override
  void performLayout(Size size) {
    int id = 1;

    getBounds(Offset.zero & size, 3).forEach(
      (rect) {
        layoutChild(id, BoxConstraints.tight(rect.size));
        positionChild(id, rect.centerRight);
        id++;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(
      covariant Avatar3xBtnMultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

And using it

```dart
class CAPG extends StatefulWidget {
  const CAPG({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CAPG> createState() => _CAPGState();
}

class _CAPGState extends State<CAPG> {
  double value = 300;
  final iconSize = 24.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Slider(
                value: value,
                max: 500,
                onChanged: (v) {
                  setState(() {
                    value = v;
                  });
                }),
            Container(
              width: value,
              height: value,
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.cyanAccent.withOpacity(.2),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(),
              ),
              child: CustomMultiChildLayout(
                delegate: Avatar3xBtnMultiChildLayoutDelegate(iconSize),
                children: [
                  LayoutId(
                      id: 1,
                      child: Material(
                        color: Colors.purple,
                        shape: CircleBorder(),
                        child: Icon(Icons.one_k, size: iconSize),
                      )),
                  LayoutId(
                      id: 2,
                      child: Material(
                        color: Colors.purple,
                        shape: CircleBorder(),
                        child: Icon(Icons.two_k, size: iconSize),
                      )),
                  LayoutId(
                    id: 3,
                    child: Material(
                      color: Colors.purple,
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                      child: Icon(Icons.three_k_outlined, size: iconSize),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: ™Not perfect but ..." then do not hardcode values like `.6`, `.7`, `.75` etc - see https://gist.github.com/pskink/50554a116698f03a862a356c38b75eb3#file-rotary_dial-dart-L154 and check `getBounds` function that computes the perfect coordinates

Comment: Thanks, @pskink  the `getBounds` method is amazing

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Stack Widget . For your Idea here is the Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new ExampleWidget()));
}

class ExampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget bigCircle = new Container(
      width: 300.0,
      height: 300.0,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.orange,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
    );

    return new Material(
      color: Colors.black,
      child: new Center(
        child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            bigCircle,
            new Positioned(
              child: new CircleButton(onTap: () => print("Cool"), iconData: Icons.favorite_border),
              top: 10.0,
              left: 130.0,
            ),
            new Positioned(
              child: new CircleButton(onTap: () => print("Cool"), iconData: Icons.timer),
              top: 120.0,
              left: 10.0,
            ),
            new Positioned(
              child: new CircleButton(onTap: () => print("Cool"), iconData: Icons.place),
              top: 120.0,
              right: 10.0,
            ),
            new Positioned(
              child: new CircleButton(onTap: () => print("Cool"), iconData: Icons.local_pizza),
              top: 240.0,
              left: 130.0,
            ),
            new Positioned(
              child: new CircleButton(onTap: () => print("Cool"), iconData: Icons.satellite),
              top: 120.0,
              left: 130.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CircleButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final GestureTapCallback onTap;
  final IconData iconData;

  const CircleButton({Key key, this.onTap, this.iconData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double size = 50.0;

    return new InkResponse(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: new Container(
        width: size,
        height: size,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        child: new Icon(
          iconData,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This works more or less well when the buttons are all spread in a straight x/y axis, but it doesn't work very well when the small buttons are positioned anywhere else than the absolute top, bottom, left and right of the large circle. Using positioned to arrange the smaller buttons in the angle I need has proven to be not really feasible, unfortunately.

Comment: This seems promising, I'll study it, thank you!